# How to execute sql function first instead of read files function JavaScript

Tags: sql, node.js, asynchronous, fs, readfile

Basically I am looking for solution which how to make JavaScript executes the SQL function before executing readfile funtion.

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
var  fs   = require("fs");
const util = require("util");

const readdir = util.promisify(fs.readdir);
```

Above: Variable declaration

```
async function app(){
 con.connect(()=>{
        con.query(
          `SELECT DISTINCT
        personel.branch
    FROM
        personel
    RIGHT JOIN TechnicianClockIn ON personel.name = TechnicianClockIn.techName
    WHERE
        TechnicianClockIn.jobCount < 4 AND TechnicianClockIn.availability=TRUE`,(err,result)=>{
          var keputusan = JSON.stringify(result[0].branch);
            console.log(keputusan);
           
        });
    });

var files = await readdir("/racuntech_assign");
console.log(files);
}

app();
```

```
PS D:\racuntech_assign> node Assign.js
[
  'Assign.js',
  'BANGI.txt',
  'node_modules',
  'package-lock.json',
  'package.json'
]
"BANGI"
```

The output that I got was it appears result of read files first instead of result of SQL. Thank you in advanced btw.

Comment: <
async function app(){
 await con.connect(()=>{
        con.query(
          `SELECT DISTINCT
        personel.branch
    FROM
        personel
    RIGHT JOIN TechnicianClockIn ON personel.name = TechnicianClockIn.techName
    WHERE
        TechnicianClockIn.jobCount < 4 AND TechnicianClockIn.availability=TRUE`,(err,result)=>{
          var keputusan = JSON.stringify(result[0].branch);
            console.log(keputusan);
           
        });
    });

var files = readdir("/racuntech_assign");
console.log(files);
}

app();
/>

Please try this. It might help.

Comment: @HemantJain Ohh okay mate. I'm trying.

Comment: You can mention if it solved your issue. It can be helpful for others.